# A game with numbers modulo $N$

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Let $N\geq 4$ be a fixed positive integer. Two players, $A$ and $B$ are forming an ordered set $\{x_1,x_2,...\},$ adding elements alternatively. $A$ chooses $x_1$ to be $1$ or $-1,$ then $B$ chooses $x_2$ to be $2$ or $-2,$ then $A$ chooses $x_3$ to be $3$ or $-3,$ and so on. (at the $k^{th}$ step, the chosen number must always be $k$ or $-k$)

The winner is the first player to make the sequence sum up to a multiple of $N.$ Depending on $N,$ find out, with proof, which player has a winning strategy.

**My attempt:**
We know that for $N=4$, the first player wins because he can change the residue modulo $N$ by $1$ or $-1$ at his moves while the other player has much more limited changing capabilities, and it is  easy to prove this.
I think that by the same logic, we know that when $N$ is a multiple of $4$, the second player cannot win but we still don't know if the first player can win or the game can continue forever.

If $N$ is divisible by 4, the first player can make sure that the second player doesn't win in this way:
We will look at the problem modulo $4$ and prove that the second player can never obtain a number divisible by $4$, thus never winning.

We will consider all numbers modulo $4$.

Player $1$ will always add/subtract $1$ or $3$, in other words, always add $-1$ or $1$. The steps go as folows:

At steps of form $4k+1$: Player $1$ adds $-1$ or $1$.
At steps of form $4k+2$: Player $2$ adds $2$ (he has no other choice).
At steps of form $4k+3$: Player $1$ adds $-1$ or $1$.
At steps of form $4k+4$: Player $2$ adds $0$ (he has no other choice).

So at the $4k+2$ the number received by player $2$ before his move is odd, so he can't win here. At the $4k+3$ steps, if player $1$ receives a number of the form $4k+1$, he can add $1$, thus giving to the second player a number that is not divisible by $4$ so player 2 can't win. In the other case, when player $1$ receives a number of the form $4k+3$, he can add $-1$, again blocking player $2$, from winning.

However we only know that player $2$ cannot win, but this does not necessarily mean that player $1$ has a winning strategy.

Source: Romanian TST 2021 Day 3, P2

Comment: A natural starting point is to try small $N$, see if you can find a pattern.

Comment: When you say "the second player cannot win", presumably this is under the assumption that the first player is successfully playing to win or at least not lose.  For example if $N=8$ and $8=-1+2+3+4$ would be a second player win, so the first player could decide to play $-3$ instead

Comment: I see your point. What I am trying to say is that the first player can play in such a way that he is sure that the second player will never win. I guess that it is also my fault for not explaining properly. I will add my full argument so it will be clear why I said that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result:

- $A$ wins for $N = 4$;
- $B$ wins for $N = 5, 6, 10$;
- neither can win for other $N$.

For the proof, there is slight difference between odd and even $N$. I will treat the case of odd $N$ here as it's simpler.

Thus fix odd $N \geq 9$.

Define $w(s, m)$ as follows: suppose the sum of all previous numbers is congruent to $s$ mod $N$ and the next number to add is $m$ mod $N$ (thus the next player can choose to add $m$ or $-m$). We define $w(s, m) = 1$ if this situation is a win for the next player to move; $w(s, m) = -1$ if this situation is a lose for the next player to move; $w(s, m) = 0$ otherwise.

Claim:

1. $w(m, \pm m) = 1$ for all $m$;
2. $w(0, -2) = w(0, \frac{N - 1}2) = w(\pm 1, 0) = -1$;
3. $w(0, -1) = w(\pm 2, -1) = 1$;
4. all other $w(s, m)$ are equal to $0$.

Proof:
It's a tedious routine check.

- $w(m, \pm m) = 1$ is clear;
- $w(0, \frac{N - 1}2) = -1$ because $w(\pm\frac{N - 1}2, \frac{N + 1}2) = 1$;
- $w(\pm1, 0) = -1$ because $w(\pm1, 1) = 1$;
- $w(0, -1) = w(\pm2, -1) = 1$ because $w(\pm1, 0) = -1$;
- $w(0, -2) = -1$ because $w(\pm 2, -1) = 1$;

and for all other $s, m$:

- none of $w(s \pm m, m + 1)$ is equal to $-1$;
- $w(s \pm m, m + 1)$ cannot be simultaneously equal to $1$.

This proves the result.

The case of even $N$ is more complicated (slightly different according to $N \equiv 0, 2$ mod $4$) but similar.

Comment: Surely $w(0,m)=-1$ for all $m$, because the player already lost on the previous move?

Comment: @TonyK In the definition of $w(s, m)$, the game is supposed to be of that status from the very beginning. Thus there is no "previous move" and $w(0, m)$ is not necessarily $-1$. However under the real gameplay (i.e. $A$ starts by choosing $\pm1$), $w(0, m)$ is an unreacheable situation, for exactly the reason you mentioned.